# Grouping two or more UIimages into one (not merging)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to group `UIImages` into one , on selecting `UIButto`n by named "ungroup" the images should be ungrouped .

I want to move two or more images to a particular point, so i will select those images in a `UIView` and group it . After one point i will ungroup those images . I dont want to merge those images . Ofcourse merging can be done using `CGBitmapContext` stuffs.

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options here:

1 - do all stuff by your own code - store groups info lists, move it one by one and so on...

2 - add grouped UIImages to another UIView and remove from superview and operate it. you will need to calculate the positions for grouped images into new uiview and convert it back after ungrouping for transfer images back to superview, I think there is the bounds (not frame)  will be helpful for you.

If I shall do this things I think I will decide to use 1st option.